# Testing the CAPM a la Fama & MacBeth: specific trade-off between expected return and risk

Tags: asset-pricing, capm, testing

Fama & MacBeth (1973) test a two-parameter model of market equilibrium by examining whether its implications hold empirically. They work with the following generalization of the model:
$$
\tilde R_{i,t} = \tilde\gamma_{0,t} + \tilde\gamma_{1,t}\beta_i + \tilde\gamma_{2,t}\beta_i^2 + \tilde\gamma_{3,t}\sigma_i + \tilde\eta_{i,t} \tag{7}.
$$

Implication (C3) of a two-parameter model is $\mathbb{E}(\tilde\gamma_{1,t})>0$, i.e. there is a positive trade-off between expected return and risk.

Fama & MacBeth state explicitly on p. 612-613 that they are not testing the CAPM but a more general two-parameter model. Now, if we were to test the CAPM by their method, we could modify the generalized model to
$$
\tilde R_{i,t}-R_{f,t} = \tilde\gamma_{0,t} + \tilde\gamma_{1,t}\beta_i + \tilde\gamma_{2,t}\beta_i^2 + \tilde\gamma_{3,t}\sigma_i + \tilde\eta_{i,t} \tag{7'}.
$$
and modify the implication (C3) to (C3'): $\mathbb{E}(\tilde\gamma_{1,t})=\mathbb{E}(R_{m,t})-R_{f,t}$ which is more specific than (C3) in case of the CAPM. (Another option would be to keep (C3) and then add (C3') as an extra implication.) I have not seen this done. Certainly, I do not have a great overview of the asset pricing literature, but I would expect to have run into this by now if this was mainstream. Have I simply overlooked this type of testing, or is there a reason why it is not done?